# Detect bb10 application goes to background

Tags: c++, qml, blackberry-10

First this is my first development using bb10 sdk and also with qml + c++, I had
I'm trying to capture the moment when the user slids from the blackberry logo, to minimize or switch app. Acording to their official documentation http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/c_appfund_applifecycle.html

There is a state windows NAVIGATOR_WINDOW_INACTIVE  that comes when the invisible() method is called,

the thing here: is that the documentation and searches I've done on internet, doesn't explain anything about were to override a method that listens for this event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found a forum post on BlackBerry's forums that looks pretty helpful:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Qt-and-BlackBerry-Platform-Services-BPS/m-p/1899589#M43314

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a subclass of QObject. If you use the project creation wizard Momentics will do this for you as applicationui.hpp and applicationui.cpp. In this class declare the following slots in application.hpp:

```
public slots:
  void asleep();
  void awake();
  void invisible();
  void thumbnail();
  void fullscreen();
```

Then in the class creation function attach the Application signals to your slots:

```
bool c = QObject::connect(Application::instance(), SIGNAL(asleep()),
        this, SLOT(asleep()));
Q_ASSERT(c);

c = QObject::connect(Application::instance(), SIGNAL(awake()),
        this, SLOT(awake()));
Q_ASSERT(c);

c = QObject::connect(Application::instance(),
        SIGNAL(invisible()), this, SLOT(invisible()));
Q_ASSERT(c);

c = QObject::connect(Application::instance(),
        SIGNAL(thumbnail()), this, SLOT(thumbnail()));
Q_ASSERT(c);

c = QObject::connect(Application::instance(),
        SIGNAL(fullscreen()), this, SLOT(fullscreen()));
Q_ASSERT(c);

Q_UNUSED(c);
```

Then define the slot functions to perform what you need to do when the application state changes into the one corresponding to the signal (I've only included one here):

```
void applicationui::asleep() {
    //configure application for sleep mode. Suspend or reduce processing, etc.
}
```

Comment: will I need backgound permission if I use the void ApplicationNui::invisible(){}

Comment: Not to use the slot, but if you want the OS to provide any cycles to your application when it is invisible then yes you will need that permission. These slots get executed when the application is trasitioning into that state. So when invisible() is called it means your application is becoming invisible (obscured, backlight off are the two main reasons). This slot gives you the opportunity to do what ever you need to get the application set up to run the way it should when invisible.